# Stuck in New Zealand due to coronavirus

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, new-zealand, covid-19, german-citizens

Extended family (2 adults, 2 kids) is currently stuck in New Zealand because of the coronavirus. Their original return flight was cancelled. They are German citizens.

They now say they don't have any possibility to leave the country since all countries where a transfer would have to occur would not let them in, not even airside transfer! Is this true?

If not, what would prevent them from buying an AKL-MEL-DOH-FRA ticket? This seems to be the only possible and viable option that prevents immigration along the route or landing in another Schengen country before. Also, Qatar seems to be the only airline that is still flying from that area and directly into Frankfurt.

Or are the special return flights announced by the German government their only chance to come home?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106029/discussion-on-question-by-sebastian-stuck-in-new-zealand-due-to-coronavirus).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For your proposed routing, Timatic **currently** says:

> - Transit - Australia (AU)
>
>   - Passengers are not allowed to transit or enter Australia.
>   - Passengers departing from New Zealand with a confirmed onward ticket on the same calendar day to return home are allowed to transit through Australia. They must remain airside and must have not been in China (People's Rep.), Iran, Italy or Korea (Rep.) in the past 14 days.
>
> (...)
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of Germany transiting through Brisbane (BNE), Darwin (DRW) or Melbourne (MEL) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 8 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> - Transit - Qatar (QA)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

So it should be possible if they can book that itinerary as a single ticket (so that luggage is checked through).

I can't find this itinerary, however I see AKL-DOH-FRA on Qatar Airways on Sunday.

Comment: Thanks! That's really weird... 40 minutes ago the AKL-DOH-FRA connection was 8000€ per person and I saw AKL-MEL-DOH-FRA for 2100€ per persion. Wow. Things change quickly. Now the fast connection is only 1840€ and the connection via MEL doesn't show up any more. I have to tell them!

Comment: Ah, this 1840€ connection only has one seat left...! There are only business class seats left. Minimum cost for the trip is 13000 NZD in two weeks, ranging up to 58000 NZD this weekend. I guess, the answer then is "no", they can't get out of NZ for the foreseeable future! Not because there wouldn't be flights but because it would be way too expensive...!

Comment: Yep, many of the tickets are extremely expensive, I see mostly around 20KEUR for 4 passengers, when there are even any flights. But there's an option via the US for 5K on Wednesday. Also do they have any travel insurance? Did they pay with a credit card? What airline were they booked on? Even if the flight is cancelled in many cases the carrier has to get them home at the earliest opportunity. Did they contact the German embassy?

Comment: Contact the German embassy and request evacuation. That won't be a high priority but if there are enough EU citizens in the same situation to fill a plane, who knows?

Comment: @o.m. They've done that, but it might take a long time.

Comment: @Sebastian Rescue flights are being out together right now - https://www.stuff.co.nz/business/120582267/air-nz-helping-fly-home-15000-stranded-germans-and-europeans

Comment: Qatar is actively increasing their flights worldwide, so I'd suggest hanging on for a few days.  That said, I'd also posit that they're almost certainly safer waiting this out in NZ than in Germany, so I'd seriously consider that option as well...

Comment: @lambshaanxy Waiting it out abroad may be practically and economically difficult.

Comment: @gerrit Sure.  But it would still be safer.

Comment: @o.m. These days, "fill" and "plane" make me uneasy when they're in the same sentence.

Answer (score 34):

Have they looked at the [German Embassy site for New Zealand](https://wellington.diplo.de/nz-de)?

The first link of that page leads to the [Covid-19: Informationen für Reisende](https://wellington.diplo.de/nz-de/botschaft/-/2314458) page that gives details about the present situation.

Have they registred in the **ELEFAND** as well at the **www.rueckholprogramm.de**?

- the latter is needed so that the Embassy knows who needs help

> Hierfür gilt unverändert: Eine Registrierung bei der Krisenvorsorgeliste „ELEFAND“ ersetzt nicht die Registrierung bei **www.rueckholprogramm.de**

Without this information the Embassy will not know who needs help, nor be able to plan for the needed capacities.

The return program ([Rückholaktion](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/ReiseUndSicherheit/-/2320116)) is expected to take up to 2 more weeks (2020-03-27 06:47) for most cases. More difficult cases (peaple in isolated areas) may take longer. Source: [Liveblog zur Corona-Krise](http://www.tagesschau.de/newsticker/liveblog-coronavirus-135.html)

> **I have another EU nationality, not German.  Can I fly too?**
>   For people who have another EU nationality, we will try to find a solution within the capacities.

---

**Sources**

- [Deutsche Botschaft Wellington - Auswärtiges Amt](https://wellington.diplo.de/nz-de)

  - [Coronavirus / Covid-19: Informationen für Reisende - Auswärtiges Amt](https://wellington.diplo.de/nz-de/botschaft/-/2314458)
  - [Rückholaktion - Auswärtiges Amt](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/ReiseUndSicherheit/-/2320116)

Answer (score 11):

The Deutschlandfunk news today talked about the recovery flights and mentioned that smaller Pacific islands were difficult, **so they were going to stage the recovery through New Zealand.**

At a wild guess, the flight(s) would carry Germans stuck in NZ, too.